# Unable to get an external js file to html

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, firebase, express

So I was just trying to run a firebase app, and when running locally I'm getting an error from the chrome console: `GET http://localhost:5000/behaviors/signup.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I feel that I have to set firebase.json source and destination under rewrites or would add a route for it at index.js?

index.hbs:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../behaviors/signup.js"></script>`

index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const engines = require('consolidate');

const app = express();
app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/",
      "function": "app"
    }]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

Comment: what should be the correct path to connect? if in src you start typing a `/`  it is an absolute path from your project index

Comment: I mean the app is able to run, I just don't understand why it is unable to source my external js file which I've defined in index.hbs. I believe my script source is accurate but obviously not. Should I add properties at firebase.json?

Answer (score 0):

app.use(express.static('public')); // To serve static files